# How to point candy machine to domain name?

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine

Havent been able to find much on this at all, on here or on google. But I currently have my own domain, and i want to host my candy machine on it. how would I go about doing that? I've been trying to look around for config files to change it from spinning up on localhost but i havent been able to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, you just need to host your website somewhere, best place would be **netlify.com (they are free)**. Put your files in github and host files on Netlify, then in settings change domain to custom domain! That's it! More details on how to host it - [Youtube guide on how to host website on netlify](https://youtube.com/watch?v=OPalwvWO63U)

It's super cool, because you can push to github and it will automatically update the website.